# Firebird - Select para unir duas ou mais linhas

Tags: select, firebird

Tenho uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

```
Cliente_id  |  credito  |  debito  |  pedido
     1           100                    1
     1                       150        1
     1            30                    1
     2                       200        2
     2           180                    2
```

Como fazer um Select que o resultado seja semelhante ao abaixo?

```
Cliente_id  |  credito  |  debito  |  pedido
     1           130         150        1
     2           180         200        2
```

Grato pela ajuda de vocês

Answer (score 1, accepted):

acho que seria algo assim

```
select Cliente_id, SUM(credito), SUM(debito), pedido from tabela group by pedido
```

onde esta tabela vc troca para o nome de sua tabela, o que eu fiz foi agrupar as infos dos mesmos pedidos e somar o valor

Comment: funcionou corretamente. obrigado

Answer (score 2):

pode ser assim também:

```
select t.Cliente_id, CAST(SUM(t.credito) as numeric(15,2)), CAST(SUM(t.debito) as NUMERIC(15,2)), t.pedido,

CAST(SUM(t.credito) as numeric(15,2)) - CAST(SUM(t.debito) as NUMERIC(15,2)) as Saldo

FROM NOMEDATABELA T 

group by
t.Cliente_id, t.pedido
```

Inseri também uma coluna de saldo, já tem apenas 1 linha a mais.